# Keep Tipsy tooltip from fading out when mousing over

Tags: jquery, tooltip

I want to use the tipsy tooltip as a toolbar. When hovering a link I would like the toolbar to show, let's say a div, and when entering the toolbar area I want it to stay visible, not hide. So my questions are:

- How do I show a hidden div?
- How do I keep the tooltip visible when entering the tooltip area?

Comment: It sounds like you should really be using a library other than tipsy. Tipsy does tooltips, and that's about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tipsy supports "manual" triggering.  So what you'd want to do is have the "onmouseover" event on your link call the `tipsy('show')` function, and then for the hiding part, well... probably do two things:  when you do your show, set a timeout that auto-hides after x seconds.  Then also set a onmouseout event for your tooltip that calls `tipsy('hide')`.

**EDIT**: changed the code to something that actually works, see here:  http://jsfiddle.net/6FpM8/3/  Thanks to @Josh for poking me to get it working.

```
var timer;

//setup the toolbar and tipsy
$('#mylink').attr('title','Input here:<input id="toolbar">');
$('#mylink').tipsy({trigger:'manual',gravity:'w', html:true});

//.tipsy class is what the generated tooltip divs have, so we use the 
//live event to link the mouseover/mouseout events
$('.tipsy').live('mouseover',function(e){
  clearTimeout(timer);
});
$('.tipsy').live('mouseout',function(e){
  timer = setTimeout("$('#mylink').tipsy('hide');",3000);//hide the link in 3 seconds
});

//manually show the tooltip
$('#mylink').bind('mouseover',function(e){
   $(this).tipsy('show');
 });
```

Comment: I've tried this myself and would love to up-vote your answer, but haven't gotten this to work myself. Have you tried this yourself and had it work?

Comment: @Josh, yes I just set it up now, seems to work as I imagined:  http://jsfiddle.net/6FpM8/

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here, but that tooltip doesn't have the id `mytoolbar`. And when using the class `tipsy` it still doesn't work.

Comment: indeed, I wasn't paying very close attention there... How about this:  http://jsfiddle.net/6FpM8/3/

Comment: that works splendidly. I'm trying to get this manual triggering to work with `delayIn`. Would appreciate your help here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3758657/jquery-tipsy-manual-triggers-and-delayin

Answer (score 0):

I did this by altering Tipsy itself.  Tipsy attaches the tooltip element to the document.body, in the Tipsy.prototype's show method:

```
$tip.remove().css({
    top: 0, 
    left: 0, 
    visibility: 'hidden', 
    display: 'block'}).appendTo(document.body);
```

If you change the tip to be a child of the triggering element, then jQuery mouseleave won't fire if you are in the tooltip:

```
$tip.remove().css({
    top: 0, 
    left: 0, 
    visibility: 'hidden', 
    display: 'block'}).appendTo(this.$element[0]);
```

In my case, I have a div with the title attribute that holds the tip, and the div holds the image that the user is targeting. (I don't know if this would work if the element holding the tip is childless, like an img.) I enable Tipsy on the div.