# jQuery tipsy: manual triggers and delayIn

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using the tipsy plugin for jQuery. Whenever I try to call tipsy with both a manual trigger and delayIn, the delayIn doesn't seem to work:

`$('.interest').tipsy({trigger:'manual', gravity: 'n', html: true, delayIn: 3000});`

Any ideas as to why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that once you turn on `trigger:'manual'`, tipsy doesn't take care of delayIn any more.  Your best bet might be to just have your manual trigger (wherever you do `...tipsy('show')`) do a delay instead:

```
setTimeout("\$('#link').tipsy('show');",3000);
```

You could also look at the tipsy source to see that they have a slightly more elegant version that you could work from:

```
    function enter() {
        var tipsy = get(this);
        tipsy.hoverState = 'in';
        if (options.delayIn == 0) {
            tipsy.show();
        } else {
            setTimeout(function() { if (tipsy.hoverState == 'in') tipsy.show(); }, options.delayIn);
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you want to show tipsy-tooltips for each element of a class, and you use `$('.myclass').tipsy('show');` in document.ready this will only show the tipsy-tooltip of the first element. For all elements you need to use: `$('.myclass').each(function() { $(this).tipsy('show'); });`

Comment: Just remember you can call tipsy 'show()' method with other parameters too, like this:

`$(this).tipsy('show',{fade:true});`